# Freeze in C++ program using huge vector

Tags: c++, vector, size, freeze

I have an issue with a C++ program. I think it's a problem of memory.
In my program i'm used to create some enormous std::vector (i use reserve to allocate some memory). With vector size of 1 000 000, it's ok but if i increase this number (about ten millions), my program will freeze my PC and i can do nothing except waiting for a crash (or end of the program if i'm lucky). My vector contains a structure called Point which contain a vector of double.

I used valgrind to check if there is a memory lack. But no. According to it, there is no problem. Maybe using a vector of objects is not advised ? Or maybe is there some system parameters to check or something ? Or simply, the vector is too big for the computer ?

What do you think about this ?

Comment: What are the specs of your machine? How much RAM?

Comment: It may be that your system cannot allocate a contiguous block of that size, if so, you could try using a `list`, obviously this will have a performance impact...

Comment: Can you also show some minimal code which will reproduce the problem

Comment: How many doubles are there inside each of your struct object?

Comment: @Nim I would go to `deque` first.

Comment: It should be a fairly easy task to calculate the ballpark of the expected size of your vector - add the sizes of the members and multiply by vector size

Comment: @BoBTFish, or that...

Comment: @user1158692 - `sizeof` gives the actual size of a struct. Most people get it wrong when they try to figure it out for themselves.

Comment: "if there is a memory lack" yes, I would think that a lack of more memory is the reason.

Comment: @PeteBecker Well, yeah, but maybe right enough...  : )

Comment: ...In my program i'm used to create some enormous std::vector...  Why for heaven's sake are you doing this...?

Comment: Do you really need all the data in memory *at the same time*?  Most programs with large data, only process the data in "chunks".

Comment: @PeteBecker for an intensive applied maths calculation. I work on big vectors but linear algebra library like Eigen or others didnt have tools for my purpose.

Comment: In addition to comments above: even if such a huge contiguous block of memory would theoretically fit in memory based on a size comparison, that is still no guarantee of nice program behavior. Consider that the amount of memory that is available to your program is always less than physical memory. Furthermore, you are always competing with other processes for memory. Lastly, you may trigger the OS to start swapping; which kills performance.

Comment: @pippin1289 I think i have a RAM of 4Go. I will check this tomorrow at work.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal 8 doubles

Comment: @ThomasMatthews , well i need all my data for each step of my solver. However, i can maybe use "chunks" for the initialisation of all my data, but i don't know how to do.

Comment: @user3046300 In that case I'd seriously suggest you go over your design, with the explicit goal of: (1) reworking it to allow you to introduce 'divide and conquer' in your calculations or (2) restating the problem in such a way that the amount of vectors required is reduced significantly or (3) both (1) and (2).

Comment: @user3046300 Based on your comments consider updating your question to include your exact problem. Instead of trying to solve your current  memory-related problem, inquire about a solution to your real problem instead.

Answer (score 4):

#### Disclaimer

Note that this answer assumes a few things about your machine; the exact memory usage and error potential depends on your environment. And of course it is even easier to crash when you don't compute on 2d-Points, but e.g. 4d-points, which are common in computer graphics for example, or even larger Points for other numeric purposes.

#### About your problem

That's quite a lot of memory to allocate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
struct Point {
    std::vector<double> coords;
};
int main () {
    std::cout << sizeof(Point) << std::endl;
}
```

This prints `12`, which is the size in bytes of an empty `Point`. If you have 2-dimensional points, add another `2*sizeof(double)=8` to that per element, i.e. you now have a total of 20 bytes per `Point`.

With 10s of millions of elements, you request 200s of millions of bytes of data, e.g. for 20 million elements, you request 400 million bytes. While this does not exceed the maximum index into an `std::vector`, it is possible that the OS does not have that much contiguous memory free for you.

Also, your `vector`s memory needs to be copied quite often in order to be able to grow.  This happens for example when you `push_back`, so when you already have a 400MiB `vector`, upon the next `push_back` you might have your old version of the `vector`, plus the newly allocated 400MiB*X memory, so you may easily exceed the 1000MiB temporarilly, et cetera.

#### Optimizations (high level; **preferred**)

Do you need to actually *store* the data all time? Can you use a similar algorithm which does not require so much storage? Can you refactor your code so that storage is reduced? Can you core some data out when you know it will take some time until you need it again?

#### Optimizations (low level)

If you know the number of elements before creating your outer vector, use the `std::vector` constructor which you can tell an initial size:

```
vector<Foo> foo(12) // initialize have 12 elements
```

Of course you can optimize a lot for memory; e.g. if you know you always only have 2d-Points, just have two `double`s as members: 20 bytes -> 16 bytes. When you do not really need the precision of `double`, use `float`: 16 bytes -> 8 bytes. That's an optimization to $2/5$:

```
// struct Point { std::vector<double> coords; };   <-- old
struct Point { float x, y; }; // <-- new
```

If this is still not enough, an ad-hoc solution could be `std::deque`, or another, non-contiguous container: No temporal memory "doubling" because no resizing needed; also no need for the OS to find you such contiguous block of memory.

You can also use compression mechanisms, or indexed data, or fixed point numbers. But it depends on your exact circumstances.

```
struct Point { signed char x, y; }; // <-- or even this? examine a proper type
struct Point { short x_index, y_index; };
```

Comment: I would go with `std::deque` before trying to change all of the logic around to use `std::list`.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, this is just speculation, but I suspect it is in large part due to your attempt to allocate a massive amount of memory that is *contiguous*.  `std::vector` is guaranteed to be in contiguous memory, so if you try to allocate a large amount of space, the operating system has to try to find a block of memory that large that it can use.  This may not be a problem for 2MB, but if you are suddenly trying to allocate 200MB or 2GB of contiguous memory ...

Additionally, anytime you add a new element to the vector and it is forced to resize, all of the existing elements must be copied into the new space allocated.  If you have 9 million elements and adding the 9,000,001 element requires a resize, that is 9 million elements that have to be moved.  As your vector gets larger, this copy time takes longer.

Try using `std::deque` instead.  It is will basically allocate pages (that will be contiguous), but each page can be allocated wherever it can fit.