# Array of size 226MB "rejected" by gcc

Tags: c++, memory, gcc, memory-management, g++

I am trying to initialize the following array in my program.

```
glm::vec4 array[300000][60000];
```

The size of glm::vec4 is 16 Bytes. Hence the approximate size of this array is 226MB.

Howveer gcc simply terminates this program. Any help why this is happening ?

Platform : Intel i7 with Ubuntu and 8GB of RAM

Comment: Your math is wrong.  The exact size is 288 GB.

Comment: Something like this was actually asked earlier today on SO....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475295/freeze-in-c-program-using-huge-vector/20475643#20475643

Comment: @DietrichEpp almost, it's 300000*60000*16/(2^30) bytes == 268.22 GB.

Comment: Either way, it's quite big.  You 64-bit?

Comment: Yes its 64bit platform

Comment: @DietrichEpp : I used the following calculation. //Lets do soem calculations 
 glm::vec4 dummy;
 uint sizeofglm = sizeof(dummy);
 double totsize = sizeofglm * 300000 * 60000;
 double sizeinmb = totsize/(1024.0*1024.0);
 std::cout << "Total size of glmvec4 DS:" << sizeinmb << " \n";

Comment: This is showing 226MB and not GB. Can you tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: 16 * 300,000 * 60,000 = 288,000,000,000 bytes.  Convert to GB or MB however you want, but it's 288 billion bytes however you slice it.

Comment: @rajaditya_m: You're using `int` values, and `int` multiplication on your platform is apparently 32 bits. You convert to `double` only after it already overflowed. Try `* 300000.0 * 60000.0`

Comment: @Adam: SI prefix "G" means 1,000,000,000.  That's the international standard, and that's the meaning I use.

Comment: Yup I found the flaw. Thanks for the clarification. My code messed up the floating point numbers

Comment: @DietrichEpp When talking about bytes the SI units are at best profoundly useless and at worst silently misleading. Everything (other than hard drive marketing) uses even numbers like 2^10 instead of 1000 when talking about bytes. So a GB is a useless number without another conversion, or it's simply interpreted as GiB and the wrong figure is understood. Anyway, enough off-topicness.

Comment: @Adam: This isn't the right forum to advocate for your preferred numbering system.  My terminology matches that of SI and IEC.  If you want to redefine GB, talk to them.

Comment: It is not `gcc` which terminates your program. But probably, your `main` has such a huge [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) frame that it cannot run. So termination happens (very early) at run-time. And declaring huge local variables is shameful.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler probably prohibits ridiculously big stack frames.

Either relax this restriction with a compiler switch or some such or reach for free store.